# Remote access to Wildfly 10 (Server Starting at Eclipse)

Tags: wildfly, remote-access, wildfly-10

**Im trying to remotely access to Wildfly from other pc in local network**(no localhost) and I can only do that if I run the server (with standalone.bat) that way:

```
standalone.bat -b=0.0.0.0
```

**The problem is that I don't wanna to do this manually each time I run the server**, I tried editing standalone.xml that way:

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:0.0.0.0}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="unsecure">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:0.0.0.0}"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```

But dont work, also tried to do the same through the wildfly UI but also don't work, what im doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you're using windows I think you can `set "SERVER_OPTS=-b 0.0.0.0"` in file `standalone.conf.bat` inside `bin` directory. However setting your public interface to all network adapters like you did in standalone.xml should also work. You have to restart your server though.

Comment: You can also use `JAVA_OPTS` and set the `jboss.bind.address` to `0.0.0.0`. Are you by chance overriding that anywhere? That configuration should resolve to `0.0.0.0` assuming the `jboss.bind.address` is not set.

Comment: Thanks guys both options work:
    `set "SERVER_OPTS=-b 0.0.0.0"` &
    `set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0"`
But I don't know why if I launch server from eclipse this configuration is not loaded :/

Comment: For Eclipse. Open server configuration (double click on server). And click link "Open launch configuration" under "General Information". Add VM arguments.

Comment: ty so much dude :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open server configuration (double click on server). And click link "Open launch configuration" under "General Information". Add VM arguments. – "Qwertovsky"